# How switch "mouseover - addClass" fields with fadetoggle?

Tags: jquery, navigation, mouseover, addclass

Please help me!

- I have two fields (field1, field2) that perform navigation functions
- These fields toggles the other two fields through "AddClass"
- I need to perform this operation in effect "fadeToggle"

---

```
$(function () {
   $('#field1').mouseover(function() {
      $('#d1').addClass('over1');
   }).mouseover(function(){
      $('#d2').removeClass('over2');
   });
   $('#field2').mouseover(function() {
      $('#d2').addClass('over2');
   }).mouseover(function(){
      $('#d1').removeClass('over1');
   });
});
```

it was not carried through the "hover" as necessary that the fields do not disappear

Comment: There's no fading effect on just swapping classes (unless you're using jQuery UI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
$(function () {
      $('#field1').mouseover(function () {
          $('#d2').fadeOut(function () {
              $('#d1').fadeIn();
          });
      });
      $('#field2').mouseover(function () {
          $('#d1').fadeOut(function () {
              $('#d2').fadeIn();
          });
      });
});
```

See JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8P5vx/2/

EDIT: I'm a little confused about what exactly you want. Maybe more like this?

```
$(function () {
    $('#field1').mouseover(function () {
        $('#d1').fadeIn();
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $('#d1').fadeOut();
    });
    $('#field2').mouseover(function () {
        $('#d2').fadeIn();
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $('#d2').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8P5vx/3/

EDIT 2:
Okay, here's probably what you want (fade in/out simultaneous, they stay visible when mouse isn't over either):

```
$(function () {
    $('#field1').mouseover(function () {
        $('#d2').fadeOut();
        $('#d1').fadeIn();
    });
    $('#field2').mouseover(function () {
        $('#d1').fadeOut();
        $('#d2').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8P5vx/4/

Comment: Well! Possible to make as that animation "simultaneous"?
That would be when the first unit began to fade, The other began to emerge?

Comment: but your second example, in contrast to the first - if you remove the cursor from the field - our field with the content also disappears (and it is very bad)

Comment: Right, I wasn't sure what you wanted; it's easy to change it so that doesn't happen.